# Set name of related list on contact

Tags: related-list, opportunitycontactrole

I have Opportunities that link directly to a contact with a custom master detail field, and that link to a contact via a Contact Role. One Opportunity record type (general) will use the custom Master-detail field. The other record type (department) uses the contact role. This means on my contact that we have two related lists for Opportunities. I'm wondering if there way a way to rename only one of them, preferably the contact role one. I'd want to name it something like "Departments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for renaming related lists can be found [here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000175965&language=en_US).

As you wish to rename a standard object, it looks like this won't give you what you want because if you rename the Opportunity object to something else, then you will still have two Opportunity related lists on the contact page, just with a different name.

If there's a valid business reason, you could use contact record types and page layouts to just have 1 Opportunity related list.

Another approach, if you really wanted to, would be to grab the data from one object, and automatically insert it into a custom object, and you would have the autonomy to rename the custom object related list whatever you wished and display that on the contact page layout too. Process Builder should suffice here, you no coding required.

Answer (score 1):

To rename related lists resulting from a custom relationship (Object Relationships Overview), we will need to locate the custom relationship field on the child object:

1. If the child object is a custom object: From Setup, go to Create > Objects > (Name of Object).
   If the child object is a standard object: From Setup, go to Customize > (Name of Object) > fields.
2. Locate the custom lookup or master-detail field referencing the parent object.
3. Click the "Edit" link next to the relationship field.
4. Rename the "Related List Label".
5. Remember to "Save" when finished.

To rename related lists resulting from a standard relationship (Object Relationships Overview), such as Opportunities and Accounts, we will need to rename the child object:

1. From Setup, go to Customize > Tab Names and Labels > Rename Tabs and Labels
2. Click the "Edit" link next to the name of the child object.
3. Rename the Singular and Plural labels.
   (Please note that only the Plural label is used to title related lists)
4. Remember to "Save" when finished.

Comment: Nicely done, and welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite do what I need.  As Andy pointed out, I am wanting to change the label for a standard object. Either way I will have two objects with the same name. 
What I really want to do is to be able to rename the Contact Role relationship, but that's not an option, and is probably not something that will ever be an option.